# Intents and sharing my application

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share, android-intent

I am having a lot of trouble getting my Sharing of my application to work.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {        
        case R.id.exit: System.exit(0);
            break;

        case R.id.icontext: String url = "http://www.manaforged.com";
            String shareText = url + "\nCheck this gaming community out!";
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));
            break;            
    }
    return true;
```

I only get 2 options Gmail and some other random thing. I see screen shots of others using roughly the same code with a lot more options. I have facebook app ect installed on my phones. Did the API change and I am viewing old information? I am getting very frustrated with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

change `sendIntent.setType("plain/text")` to `sendIntent.setType("text/plain")`
it will solve your problem..